# ASP.NET Repeater Control Not Working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, repeater

everyone:

I have an ASP.NET Application that uses a Repeater control to display a thumbnail gallery. When the user mouses over one of the thumbnails, the main image will present that thumbnail.

It uses a Repeater control in a UserControl like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="pictureImage" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="200px" />
<asp:Repeater ID="rpProductImages" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <div style="float: left" id="smallImage" runat="server">
                <div class="smallAltImage" onmouseover="showImage();" 
                    style="border: 1px solid #999999; margin: 5px 5px 5px 4px;
                    width: 45px; height: 45px; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                    background-image: url('<%#ResolveClientUrl(productImagesPath)%><%# String.Format("{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageName")) %>');">
                </div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblImageName" runat="server" Visible="false"><%# Eval("ImageName")%></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then, in a javascript file, this:

```
function showImage(){
    // Get thumbnail path.
    var img = (this.style.backgroundImage).substring(4, (this.style.backgroundImage).length - 1);
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ProductDetails1_pictureImage').attr('src', img);
}
```

It works fine in IE9, displaying the fully-qualified path for the image. In FireFox8, however, the img src looks like this:  ""ProductImages/K42JY_500.jpg"" ... with two-sets of quotes!

I think that the Repeater control is the central cause of the problem but I Googled and Googled again and could not find anyone that has experienced this similar situation!

Comment: Can you show the full HTML that is generated for the page in in FireFox?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be guessing what IDs the repeater will generate, and then hard-code against that.  ASP.NET 4 supports more predictive name generation, or you could use CSS classes.

Also, unless this function is called as a method on an object, `this` will be equal to the global object, which I doubt is what you want.

```
function showImage(){
    // Get thumbnail path.
    var img = (this.style.backgroundImage).substring(4, (this.style.backgroundImage).length - 1);
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ProductDetails1_pictureImage').attr('src', img);
}
```

Comment: I actually fixed it myself. Whew! Sweating that I might have to give multiple people money! Basically, I just used 5, 2 for the parms in the var img line of code to strip out the offensive quotes. Thanks to all the peeps who wrote in, though! Your the reason this place is so good.

Comment: @RobertHyland Sure thing -- Glad you got it working.  If either of these answers were helpful, feel free to accept or upvote them—which you now have the ability to do after my +1 on this question :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the ASP.NET Repeater is the problem.  It is either the HTML that is in your ItemTemplate tag, the javascript itself, or the difference between IE and Firefox.

First, validate the output-ed HTML with an HTML validator.  Fix any problems. Then debug your javascript in Firefox to see what it is doing.  Maybe firefox includes the double quotes in the value of this.style.backgroundImage.

Also, make this:

```
<%# String.Format("{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageName")) %>
```

like this to simplify

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageName") %>
```

Comment: Agreed about the repeater is not the issue, as the repeater is a server side control, so the browser in use has no bearing in this.

Comment: +1 There are single quotes within `background-image: url('')` and the asp outputs also double quotes due to the `String.Format` resulting in `background-image('"..."');`. You spotted this correctly. I'm not sure whether your answer resolves the issue but it certainly improves the OP code.